# Real purchases not available in TestFlight

Tags: ios, flutter, in-app-purchase, testflight, in-app

We had an app developed years before and now we are developing in Flutter and we want to test our old, real purchases, but on TestFlight, we don't see them, but we only see our old purchases done on the last TestFlight made years ago.

We can buy on TestFlight all the In-App Products normally without costs, but we want to test our real purchases from the old app.

We have the same Bundle ID, a newer version, and the products have the same IDs.

Comment: Have you integrated in_app_purchase package to list your products in flutter app? or Any Other Flutter Package?

Comment: We have integrated this package https://pub.dev/packages/in_app_purchase

Comment: Can you share the exact error from error log, or part of code which you think is not working

Comment: We don’t hava any errors, we only don’t receive old real purchases, we receive only purchases that we did in the TestFlight.

Comment: Can you please elaborate your exact problem. I didn't understand exact techinal issue which you are facing?

Comment: I think it's not a technical issue. When we are on the testflight, we get all the purchases, that we made in the testflight, but when I want to get old read purchases, we got nothing. Has it to do maybe, that all purchases stays in the testflight and can't we used later? We want only to get real purchases that we made with the old app. thats all

Comment: This is a part from our code: await InAppPurchase.instance.restorePurchases().catchError((e) {
      print('Got error: $e'); // Finally, callback fires.
      return -1; // Future completes with 42.
    }).then((value) {
    });

And:

Future<void> _listenToPurchaseUpdatedBooks(List<PurchaseDetails> purchaseDetailsList) async {

    String inhaltPakete="";
    for (var i = 0; i < purchaseDetailsList.length; i++) {

      PurchaseDetails purchaseDetails=purchaseDetailsList[i];
      inhaltPakete+=purchaseDetails.productID+"\n";

    }

The result is 0.

Answer (score 0):

We have integrated this package
https://pub.dev/packages/in_app_purchase